# Too many splitting iterations while enforcing constraints

Tags: anylogic

I am getting the following error in anylogic: **Too many splitting iterations while enforcing constraints. Last split point was at: [ POINT ( -1028.5788383248864 -1017.4999999999998 ) ]**. I can't figure out why this is happening. This happens with the placement of a particular item in the simulation environment, but I can't figure out why. Any insights would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to anylogic support this is a known bug which will be fixed in the next release. So at this point not much that can be done.

Comment: still not fixed :D... august 28 2022

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is from an optimization experiment? You might want to consider relaxing your constraints or reducing some of the parameters of your model. Perhaps also consider sending your model to AnyLogic support for details about the error as it is an internal error.